# C# get value from a LinkedList

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm currently working in a program which contains a class named LinkedList. It uses nodes to create the functions Add at beginning, Insert At Position, Get Info at position and Eliminate at position. I'm having trouble with the Get function because it's not getting the correct value from the list and I don't know exaclty why.

The definition for Node in the program is:

```
        public class Node<T>
    {
        public T value;
        public Node<T> next;
    }
```

The code for the Get function is:

```
        public T Get(int index)
    {
        if (start == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Nothing to show");
        }
        if (index == 0)
        {
            return start.value;
        }
        Node<T> previous = start;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            previous = previous.next;
        }

        return previous.value;
    }
```

Also, I have these tests where my code is failing when the Get is used. The lists are created when the class LinkedList is used an then, it uses his attributes to invoke the Add, Get, AddAt and Eliminate functions in the tests.

```
        [Test]
    public void AddMultipleThenGetAll ()
    {
        LinkedList<int> linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
        linkedList.Add(42);
        linkedList.Add(43);
        linkedList.Add(44);

        int[] results = new int[] { 42, 43, 44 };
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
        {
            if (linkedList.Get(i) != results[i])
                Assert.Fail();
        }
        Assert.Pass();
    }

        [Test]
    public void AddMultipleAndRemoveInTheMiddle()
    {
        LinkedList<int> linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
        linkedList.Add(42);
        linkedList.Add(43);
        linkedList.Add(44);
        linkedList.Remove(1);

        Console.WriteLine(linkedList);
        Assert.AreEqual(44, linkedList.Get(1));
    }
```

The rest of functions are working properly.

Comment: How do you create the list? Which value are you getting and which are you expecting? Please provide a [mre]. Specifically how is `Add` implemented?

Comment: Look at the `for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)` loop in your `Get` method. Pay attention to the range of values it iterates over. Then look at the body of the for loop, and you should hopefully realize that you have crafted a off-by-one bug here. If you still struggle to understand, use the debugger to step through the iterations of this `for` loop and observe how the variable `previous` changes.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are writing your own `LinkedList` class, you're not using `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>`. This phrase (_"a program which contains a class named LinkedList"_) could go either way

Comment: Yes, I'm writing my own LinkedList.

Comment: You have bug in Add method. Also note, that complexity of Get() method is O(N), meaning that getting all elements by index will take O(N^2). Which means that for 1 million items your first test will never complete

Comment: Use the debugger - add break points and run step by step with watch to see what your code is doing vs. what you expect it to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `for` loop in your `get` method has a bug. You are looping all the way to your desired index then setting `previous` to the next item, which doesn't exist or it isn't the index / item you want. Try this instead.

```
Node<T> previous = start;
for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
{
     previous = previous.next;
}
return previous.value;
```